# NullPointerException in a service test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, service

I have a service that takes some values from SharedPreferences and do something based on the value it took. The problem is that i always get NullPointerException everywhere because i can't find a context. My test code is this. Can you help me?

```
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        mam=getService();
    }
    public void testStart()
    {
        //Test 1
        SharedPreferences pref = mam.getSharedPreferences("settings", mam.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("hour", -1); 
        editor.putInt("minute", -1); 
        editor.commit();
        mam.startService(new Intent()); //onCreate() or something else
        boolean ok=mam.getOk();
        assertFalse("T.38", ok);
    }
```

My service is this:

```
public void onCreate() 
{   
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int h=pref.getInt("hour", -1);
    int m=pref.getInt("minute", -1);
    if(h!=-1 && m!=-1)
    {
        ...
        ok=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your initialization code as well? Also, what line are you getting the NullPointerException on? Provide a stack trace if you can.

Comment: Everytime i use mam. I wrote `mam=getService();` in the `setUp()` method, but now i think that it doesn't work as it does for activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
mam.startService(new Intent());
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mam,ServiceClassName.class);
mam.startService(intent);
```

Comment: i still get NullPointerException everytime i  try to use mam. How should i initialize it?

Comment: I wrote `mam=getService();` in the `setUp()` method, but now i think that it doesn't work as it does for activities.

Comment: I added my full test class. And there is nothing else in the service class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40884/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-as-as)